# Why positioning absolute element in the center of it's parent relative element while setting top and left to 50% does not work?

Tags: html, css

I have learned that the **"absolute"** position will position the Html element relative to the parent element that should have other position then static.

I wonder why while setting the **top** and **left** property of the child element to **50%** while it's position is absolute and the one of its parent is relative does not work? Logically it should work. I really wonder why?
Once I add this property :  `translate(-50%, -50%)` to the childe it centered.

I wonder why what I did that seems very logical does not work?!!!!

Any explanation, please?

Here is my code:

```css
article{
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: bisque;
     position: relative;
}
article div{
    width:55%;
    height:110px;
    position: absolute;    
    top:50%;
    left:50%; 
    background-color: blue;
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}
article p {
    font-size: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <article>
        <div>
            <p>
                Hello Word !
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>
</body>
```

Comment: top/left will place the top-left corner of the element in the center

Comment: Well thank u for the link but I have not understood ur comment . what do u mean exactly coz the top-left corner in my case is not in the center in this way!

Comment: it's on the perfect center: https://jsfiddle.net/1vq9d7g0/

Comment: But what I mean by the center is that the center point of the div fit the center point of article :). I do not know how to explain it but u really pay my attention to something very important. thank u

Comment: that's why we use translate in this case (all explained in the duplicate)

Comment: I have understood thank u so much for this it's new to me. thank u :D.